# How to find out if my MBR has Evil Maid code?

Tags: encryption, attacks, truecrypt, boot

If Truecrypt Bootloader will remain visually the same, how can I find out if it was infected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind would be some sort of custom bootable USB stick that you keep with you. When you come back to your computer you first insert and boot from it, and it could scan your disk's MBR for changes. The USB device could then report a change and rewrite the MBR if needed.

You could consider using a software solution that once booted, would detect if a change occurred after the fact, but it's possible that would be too late as you can't be sure what the MBR virus will do. If it's truly a simple evil maid then maybe it just records the password you entered in, which you could change and possibly be fine, but that is a risk you probably don't want to take. There are many MBR viruses that do much more damage than recording passwords like the evil maid attack.